# Sidebar with overflow background color

Tags: html, css

I want to make standard layout with header, content (main area and aside sidebar) and footer. The right sidebar has background-color not only inside them but this background I want to make overflow on all body (inlcude header and footer).

It should looks like:
[image]

My idea was created it by absolute block :before sidebar but when I'm positioning it absolute with overflow body it makes scrolls (vertical and horizontal).

```
aside.sidebar:before {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #eee;
   top: -9999px;
   left: 0;
   bottom: -9999px;
   right: -9999px;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

code: http://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/yrk40e1h/1/ (based on Twitter Bootstrap)

Maybe you have better idea or you can fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid the kind of `-9999px` and stuff like that.

http://jsfiddle.net/yrk40e1h/7/

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .sidebar:before {
        content: '';
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #eee;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-left: -15px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

The negative `margin-left` is here to deal with the bootstrap **columns** padding. Tried a few things to deal with this, if someone would have a *cleaner* solution than this negative margin, your comment is very welcome.

The `@media (min-width: 768px)` is here to deal with the bootstrap **responsive columns**. Without this, when you scale down under *768px*, all this `:before` would take all the body.

Comment: thank you, this solution looks perfect! I will test it in my project and I will let you know if I had any problems

Comment: Edit your post or comment here if you have any problem related to this. Otherwise if it works, *accept* this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:fixed` with `vw/vh` or you can simply but the before on the body with `height:100%` and the same width (`%/px`) as the sidebar.
http://jsfiddle.net/yrk40e1h/4/

Comment: I checked this method, but it is not good solution. You cannot perfect set background like this. E.g. start position background (fixed position) is depend of exist vertical scroll!

Answer (score 0):

I've created new code for you. Please follow this. May this help you.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
main:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
aside {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
aside:before {
  content: '';
  background: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -99999px;
  right: -99999px;
  bottom: -99999px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1
}
.left-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <aside>
      <h3>Sidebar here</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
    </aside>
    <div class="left-content">
      <h2>Main content here</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget accumsan risus. Curabitur ac velit nec dui fringilla sodales et feugiat massa. Nullam nec luctus elit. Integer sed fermentum lorem. Nullam consequat elit nunc. Integer eget condimentum
        turpis. Quisque egestas ultricies ultricies. Nunc laoreet, tellus at euismod imperdiet, justo enim faucibus ex, at ultrices urna enim id augue. Donec ut dolor eros. Fusce sagittis euismod justo, eu ultricies ex. Vestibulum quis dolor auctor mauris
        porttitor pretium.</p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: This kind of "-99999px" is so dirty now. You should avoid doing that.

Comment: if I understand correctly, your solution is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673409/sidabar-with-overflow-background-color/31673699#31673699 (body-wrap element with overflow:hidden)?

Comment: First, you're using `position: absolute;` which is not good. Second we should use `overflow: hidden;` there no solution for this scenario using only `css`

Comment: @RedBreast what else we should you?

Comment: Why using `position: absolute` would not be good? Of course there is solution with only **CSS**. I also don't get why you are "refactoring" all the css *columns* width and positioning when **Bootstrap** already do this for it. No reason to override all the template. The only part which matter here is the `:before`, which only acts as a **background**.

Comment: 1+ from me. keep it up :)